# Maximization of a functions integrals with parameters

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am trying to find the best theoretical shape to build a boat in and have gotten stuck proving/finding the best shape for the hull.The function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following equations is what I want for the hull shape(I am currently treating a 2D case and will move onto 3D later). let be a function such that $f(x)$ is continuous on a closed interval $(a,b)$ and let $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $\int\limits_a^b \sqrt {1+ (df/dx)^2}dx=1$.
What is the maximum value of $\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx$?